# Multiple sliding menu - .stop()

Tags: jquery

I have this problem. I have sliding menu (3 levels) and when I several quick cross over menu with mouse it sliding up and down several times. 
I know that jQuery function .stop() repair this but I dont know how to use it.

I have this jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('menu li').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul.menu2').slideDown().end().find('a.prvy').css('backgroundPosition','bottom center');
        var width = $(this).find('ul.menu2').css("width");
        $(this).find('ul.menu2 li ul.menu3').css("left",width);
        $(this).find('ul.menu2>li').hover(function() {
            $(this).find('ul.menu3')).fadeIn().end().find('div.text').addClass('activ');
        }, function() {
            $(this).find('ul.menu3').fadeOut().end().find('div.text').removeClass('activ');
        });

    }, function() {
        $(this).find('ul.menu2').slideUp(300).end().find('a.prvy').css('backgroundPosition','top center');
    });
});
```

I tries somethink likes:

```
 $('menu li').stop(false,trues).hover(function() {
```

But it doesnt work.

Thank you for your answers and sorry for my English.

Comment: its `stop(false,true)` you have written `stop(false,trues)` ... also try `.stop(true,true)`

Comment: $('menu li').stop(true,true).hover(function() { doesnt work. stop(false, true) also.

Answer (score 0):

try without parameters:

```
$(this).find('ul.menu2').stop().slideDown()
```

### onHover 3 level drop-down menu, is kinda **[BAD PRACTICE](http://www.message.uk.com/dropdown-menus-no-thanks)**.

- not practical for mobile users
- hard to use with touch-pad
- to complicated to navigate in general

if you must use dropdown menu, consider doing something more [subtle](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/24/designing-drop-down-menus-examples-and-best-practices/),

Comment: Its bette but when I quick cross over with mouse it get jammed. You can see it on: http://scooter-racing.eu/neweb/